# FLV premultiplied alpha channel - adding to webpage as a swf?

Tags: video, flash, flv, premultiplied-alpha

I'm very new to premultiplied alpha channel and the only application I have is Adobe Flash, I have this FLV movie file that's got a premultiplied alpha channel and I want to insert it into a webpage to play as an animation, I imported it into flash and that's where I'm a bit lost as to how to make it appear transparent

The video looks to be inverted so background is black and the animation is white so if I try to publish it like that it just stays the same so it doesn't look right, can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i found out the video I had been sent was not a working premultiplied alpha channel which is why it didn't work in the first place, I ended up creating my own using after effects which finally worked